# How to install gurobi for cvxpy?

Tags: python, gurobi, cvx

I think the official instructions are here?  https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360044290292-How-do-I-install-Gurobi-for-Python-

However running

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\win64>python3.8 setup.py install
```

gives

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
creating C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\gurobipy
error: could not create 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\gurobipy': Access is denied
```

and I can't figure out how to fix this error.  btw I have tried running as an administrator.

Comment: May be try running command prompt as administrator

Comment: @Ajay I am running cmd as an administrator but I still don't have permission